# Where can I change the "Email has already been taken" error message?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email-validation

I need customize the message error: `Email has already been taken` for email, I'm working with Ruby 1.9.2, Rails 3.1.3, Devise 1.5.3, I tried change the message in: `config/locales/devise.en.yml` and in my 
`config/locales/en.yml` but it doesn't works!

In my `models/user` I have:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :email, :message => "este mail ya sido utilizado"
```

It shows that message but it also shows: `Email has already been taken`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/8521455/1114171

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I never used Devise, but I think the "taken" message is an ActiveRecord error message (not specific to the Devise gem). If you plan on using a non-english locale I would advice you to change the default locale instead of adding non-english content to the EN one.

```
sp:
  activerecord:
    errors:
      messages:
        taken: "este %{model} ya sido utilizado"
```

Comment: Same with "confirmation" instead of "taken". You may find all standard i18n messages here : https://github.com/svenfuchs/rails-i18n/blob/f8606e62def45279f3498549f97699049135bd11/rails/locale/en-US.yml