# Change devise message "Email has already been taken"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am using devise gem in my ruby on rails application. On user signup if an email already exists then there is a default message "Email has already been taken".

I have changed this message in en.yml

```
  activerecord:
    errors:
      messages:
        taken: "User with same email already exists. Please try with another email address."
```

In view i have used:

```
<div class="notice"><%= devise_error_messages! %></div>
```

Now the message i am getting is

```
"Email User with same email already exists. Please try with another email address."
```

The problem is that "Email" is appended at the start.

Is there any other way to change this default message?

Comment: Another option: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006270/where-can-i-change-the-email-has-already-been-taken-error-message

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Change format of the message to

```
en:
  errors:
    format: "%{message}"
```

Default is `"%{attribute} %{message}"`

**UPDATE**

There is another solution. I know this is a work around, but here goes..
Remove the existing validation, and add a custom one.

```
validate :email_uniqueness

def email_uniqueness
  self.errors.add(:base, 'User with same email already exists. Please try with another email address.') if User.where(:email => self.email).exists?
end
```

Note: 
You should consider the existing user, while doing an update

Comment: Thanks for reply. Its working. Can i change the format for this message only ??

Comment: AFIK, you can't. You will have to interpolate all the other messages to include the attribute name. Or, instead of changing the default format, you could do some regex replace on the error msg.

Comment: @Arif: If its working why don't you accept the answer?