# Customize Devise Passwords error message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, customization, custom-errors

I've a project that implements devise and I'm having trouble overriding the Passwords controller's messages.

When a wrong email address is entered by the user, Devise by default gives

`Unable to find user with email {email}`

I cant find the key to override this message in the `devise.en.yml` and can't find anything with the similar message on the devise repo as well.

Do I have an option other than to override the controller? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What is the error message you're looking for ? And in what situation ? Like `login` or `failed_login`, `password updated` `failed` ? What version of devise are you using ?

Comment: I think that error seems to be coming from `devise_token_auth`. I found the error [here](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/master/config/locales/en.yml), you don't have to override the controller for the message, you can just make the change in the file and make sure you restart `rails` server

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna, As mentioned, i want to override the message that comes when an invalid email id is passed in the forgot password form. Also, this error doesn't appear in the `devise.en.yml`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a new locale having the following structure:

```
en:
  devise_token_auth:
    passwords:
      user_not_found: "Your custom message"
```

This message will be displayed when an invalid email is passed in the forgot password form.

Originally this message comes from the `devise_token_auth` gem. But if you have the same locale in your locale files, it will override the gem's locale.

It doesn't matter which `*.en.yml file` you will put this locale into. It can be `devise.en.yml`, or you can add a new file called `devise_token_auth.en.yml`. Only the structure matters.

Comment: I had been looking in the `devise` repo and totally forgot that I'm using `devise_token_auth`. For all who come here looking, the key is [here](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/fcb1e6d22666175aa31945f7b4f0593dc111ff1c/config/locales/en.yml).

Answer (score 0):

as described in the [following link](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers) you can generate the devise controller with

```
rails generate devise:controllers user
```

then you can over-ride the `create` or `update` action. If you include `super` in the new action, it will call the parent controller action and then execute the code.

You can also over-ride the devise messages as [explained in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17570239/change-devise-message-email-has-already-been-taken), you just need to create that locale in your settings

```
en:
  devise_token_auth:
    sessions:
      not_confirmed: "your message overwritten"
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but i was hoping to find a way other than to override the controller. I really want to manage it from overriding the message [here](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/blob/master/config/locales/en.yml) but there isn't a relevant key.

Comment: They key is there `user_not_found: "Unable to find user with email '%{email}'."`. The key is `user_not_found`.

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna I had been looking into devise.en while I had to check it in devise_token_auth. Thanks though!